# How can I access data structured by labels in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I'm doing some practice with python and mysql, using pymysql. After executing a query I get the result with the following structure:

```
{'Name': 'Company1', 'SALES': 1113.3, 'CURRENCY': 'USD'}
```

I want to use the 'SALES' value for operations, how can I have access to it?

My code so far is the following:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # Revenue by Company (absolute)
            sql1 = "select `Company`.`Name`, `Company`.`SALES`, `Company`.`CURRENCY` from `Company` where `Company`.`Name` = 'Company1'"
            cursor.execute(sql1)
            result1 = cursor.fetchall()
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The result to `fetchall()` is not going to be what you described. It returns a list.  please `print` the actual output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are calling `.fetchall`, `result1` is a list of dictionaries, with each element in this list being a row returned from the query. Therefore you will need to access the `'SALES'` key in each dictionary (=row):

```
for row in results1:
    print(row['SALES'])
```

Comment: I already tried that, but I get this: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Please post the exact code that caused that error, preferrably add it to your question above.

Comment: @sobek print(result1['SALES'])

Comment: @JoseRuiz Sorry, missed the fact you are calling `fetchall`. See the updated answer

Comment: @DeepSpace That's it!! Thank you!